# Update Day and Month Except Year From Another Column

Tags: sql-server

I have table with two datetime columns in SQL Server 2000, I want to update only day and month in column_a with day and month in column_b except year.

For example:

```
column_a
----------
1/2/2009
1/2/2002
1/2/2016
3/1//1998
11/12/1987

column_b
---------
31/12/2015
11/10/2005
27/6/2017
31/12/2010
31/12/2011
```

Desired results:

```
31/12/2009
11/10/2002
27/6/2016
31/12/1998
31/12/1987
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using date literals should work in SQL Server 2000, style 112 returns the date in `YYYYMMDD` so take the `YYYY` of one and add to `MMDD` of the other and convert that to `datetime`.

```
update tablex
set columnb = convert(datetime(left(convert(varchar, column_a, 112), 4) + 
                               right(convert(varchar, column_b, 112), 4), 112)
```

It's a great deal easier in later versions. SQL Server 2000 is dead to me.

Use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ( year, month, day )

```
update tablex
set columnb = datefromparts(year(column_a),month(column_b), day(column_b))
```

Comment: This is **definitely** not available in SQL Server **2000** (!!!!) ....

Comment: @marc_s oh, no, it isn't. Mmmm, missed that. However if anyone remains on SQL 2000 they should not need an incentive to get off it.

Comment: *they should not need an incentive to get off it.* - I agree totally! :-)

Comment: I'm assuming sql 2000 has left() and right() functions... I have literally forgotten what 2000 does or does not have any longer. It was 18 years ago for goodness sake. Seriously you run a BIG RISK remaining on SQL 2000.